# Why is Ubuntu font being used in my browser when it's not even installed in my PC?

Tags: fonts

Please excuse my ignorance, I just find it weird. I am on my Win7 box. Also, only this site renders the font in my browser while design.canonical.com does not. I am pretty sure the latter uses Ubuntu font as the default the last time I logged into my Ubuntu box.

Answer (score 7):

Because this site [embeds the font itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@font-face); the canonical site just requests it, perhaps?

Comment: Confirmed using Google Chrome's [resource tracking](http://www.chromium.org/devtools/google-chrome-developer-tools-tutorial#resources): This site uses a downloadable [web font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_typography) while design.canonical.com just specifies the font's name.